# Google Analytics Core Reporting API query for exits and entrances metrics - entrance values incorrectly exactly the same as exits

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm using GA's Core Reporting API to create a report that shows the top exit pages alongside some behavioural metrics for each page. The dimension is ga:exitPagePath, and the metrics I want are:

```
ga:exits
ga:pageviews
ga:entrances
ga:avgTimeOnPage
ga:bounceRate
ga:exitRate
```

I'm sorting by `-ga:exits`. I'm not using any filters or segments.

The query appears to work fine, it doesn't return an error - however the entrances values it returns are incorrect and exactly match the exit values for each page. Other queries for `ga:entrances` without `ga:exits` give the correct entrance values.

I may have overlooked it but I can't find anywhere in the documentation indicating that these metrics can't be used together. I also tested creating a custom report within the GA interface with these two metrics and found the same result - no error or indication that I can't create a report with both metrics, but entrances incorrectly reported and exactly matching the exit values. I also get the same result in GA's Query Explorer.

Would love to work this out - it seems perfectly logical to me to want to view entrances alongside exits for exit pages :)

Answer (score 1):

A better late than never response.
It makes sense, because all users that have visited your site (entrances) have left (exits).
It gets meaningful when using it along with the pages (ga:pagePath for example).